# Fortran subroutine dsygv returns infinities

Tags: fortran, lapack

I have a problem with a subroutine solving generalized eigenproblem:

> A * x = lambda * B * x,

where A and B are supposed to be symmetric matrices, B is positive definite. I'm trying to solve the following test case 2x2

```
    program prog

      implicit none
      integer, parameter :: n=2
      integer :: work,lwork,info
      real(8) :: a(n,n), b(n,n), e(n)

      a(1,1) = -3
      a(1,2) = 4
      a(2,2) = 3
      b(1,1) = 1
      b(1,2) = 0
      b(2,2) = 1

      call dsygv(1, 'v', 'u', n, a, n, b, n, e, WORK, LWORK, INFO)

      write(6,*) info
      write(6,*) e
      write(6,*) a

   end program
```

and getting the following output:

```
    0
    -5.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000     
    -Infinity  0.44721359549995793  Infinity  0.89442719099991586
```

The eigenvalues are correct, one of the eivenvectors is correct, but I can't avoid infinities and obtain the other eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `work` and `lwork` should be arrays (double precision and integer) and they must be properly sized according to the manual. Otherwise the LAPACK will use some part of memory which it shouldn't use and everything will blow up.

There are probably other arguments wrong as well. See the source code with the instructions: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dsygv.f.html

---

A suggestion for beginners in Fortran:

Don't use `write(6,*)`, but `write(*,*)` and don't use `real(8)` but `real(dp)` where `dp` is an integer constant with the right value (use `selected_real_kind()` or other means to get the value, or just set it to 8 if you insist).

Comment: Yeah, it's ok! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Below I have suggested an update to your code, which:

- uses a portable double precision kind value (`wp`);
- displays your output using `Print`;
- sets up the (double precision) workspace `work` using LAPACK's recommended query mechanism.

Here:

```
Program prog
  Implicit None
  Integer, Parameter :: n = 2
  Integer, Parameter :: wp = kind(0.0D0)
  Integer :: info, lwork
  Real (Kind=wp) :: a(n, n), b(n, n), dummy_work(1), e(n)
  Real (Kind=wp), Allocatable :: work(:)
  External :: dsygv
  Intrinsic :: int, kind, max

  ! Workspace query:
  lwork = -1
  Call dsygv(1, 'v', 'u', n, a, n, b, n, e, dummy_work, lwork, info)
  lwork = int(dummy_work(1))
  Allocate (work(max(1,lwork)))

  a(1, 1) = -3
  a(1, 2) = 4
  a(2, 2) = 3
  b(1, 1) = 1
  b(1, 2) = 0
  b(2, 2) = 1

  Call dsygv(1, 'v', 'u', n, a, n, b, n, e, work, lwork, info)

  Print *, 'info: ', info
  If (info==0) then
    Print *, 'e: ', e
    Print *, 'a: ', a
  end If

End Program
```

With my compiler I get the output

```
 info:  0
 e:   -5.0000000000000000   5.0000000000000000
 a:   -0.8944271909999159   0.4472135954999579   0.4472135954999579   0.8944271909999159
```

Note that some vendors supply explicit interfaces for LAPACK (and BLAS) routines. You should always use these if they are available. (Doing so could have diagnosed your wrongly-typed workspace array at compile time.)